# How to make a POST request in an Angular app?

Tags: html, angular, post

Have an Angular app this app is a pop up opens on click of another application. (this another application constructs a URL (abc.com/sensitive 1/sensitive 2/ sensitive 3 /sensitive 4)) which this app calls in the router and checks whether the sensitive data is there.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'main/:sensitive1/:sensitive2/:sensitive3/:sensitive4',
    component: MainComponent,
    resolve: { sensitive1: sensitive1DetailsResolve, sensitive2: sensitive2ServiceResolve }
  },

Index.html
<body>
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <abc-root></abc-root>
</div>
</body>
```

After that user clicks on the link of my app from another app, my app pops up with all the sensitive data in it.Hence, want to do POST request for URL(abc.com/sensitive 1/sensitive 2/ sensitive 3 /sensitive 4)

Have very limited knowledge on angular, now problem is that my Angular app should be able use post method to hide all that sensitive data and should also be able to handle browser refresh too.

Please help to handle this scenario. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: As your question sits now it is very, very broad.  I recommend that you go through some Angular tutorials to familiarize yourself with how the framework works and come back with specific issues you're facing.

Comment: I have been thru few tutorials and kind of got idea how to implement http requests in angular. But not to the specific scenario above :( .

Comment: what have you tried up to now?

Answer (score 0):

Import `HttpClientModule` in app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
   ],
```

And

Import `HttpClient` in the file(generally in service.ts) where you want to make post request

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Initialize object for HttpClient in constructor

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

Now make post request for url like below, and data will be the params

```
this.http.post(url, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below is working for now....

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'sensitive1', component: MainComponent },
  { path: 'sensitive1',      component: sensitive1DetailsResolve}
  { path: 'sensitive2',      component: sensitive2DetailsResolve},
  {
    path: 'sensitive1',
    component: sensitive1DetailsComponent,
    data: { title: 'sensitiveData' }
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: 'main',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```